# Unable to access Windows 7 Temporary Internet Files using administrative share

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, internet

Unfortunately, I have the lovely task of monitoring users browsing habits; as the only administrator at a small company that does not have web filtering.  That being said, I don't have the luxury of walking to their desktops to manually browse the files, users must be unaware.

Generally, I go in using the administrative share \desktopname\C$, but on our newly added Windows 7 desktops, I find myself unable to browse the Temporary Internet Files, even when attempting to access them via c:\users\username\appdata\local.  I receive the message: ...is not accessible.  You might not have permission to use this network resource.

Humbling, considering it says to contact the administrator, and that would be me.  I'm on an XP desktop, coming across AD to a W7 Pro desktop.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: would you be able to use a service like VNC or remote desktop? if you wanted to remain discreet you would likely have to check the folders before/after hours (when the users are not on site) but it would permit you to check the folders from the local machine, remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to access those PC's directly and modify the permissions on that particular folder. Add the "Everyone" permission to that folder.

> 1)      Right-click the file or folder, and then click Properties.
>
> 2)      Click the Security tab, and then click Edit.
>
> 3)      To set permissions for a user that is not listed under Group or user names, click Add, type Everyone as the name of the user or group, click OK, select the permissions  as Full control or whatever you need, and then click OK.

Comment: This is bad from a security perspective. Instead of adding `Everyone` to the access list, which is a huge security vulnerability, you should add your user account explicitly, and grant that user full permissions. Otherwise, any user on the computer could potentially view each other's browsing info.